# In an array, list indices must be integers or slices, not str error python

Tags: python, csv, error-handling, astroquery

I have a code which reads data from .tsv file then turns its columns into arrays. However, when i try to use those arrays in for loop it says "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str". How can i fix this?

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import astropy.units as u
import astropy.coordinates as coord

column_names = ["#paper", "Object", "RA","Ra2","DEC","Dec2"]
"""data = pd.read_csv ("jwebb.tsv", sep = '\t')"""


data=pd.read_csv("jwebb.tsv", sep = '\t', names=column_names)

STARS=data.Object.to_list()
RA=data.RA.to_list()
DEC=data.DEC.to_list()




for i in STARS:
    from astroquery.simbad import Simbad
    result_table = Simbad.query_object(STARS[i], wildcard=True)
    print(result_table)
```

Answer (score 0):

A dataframe has no attribute called 'Object', 'RA', or 'DEC'. If those are columns you have to access them using:

```
Stars = data["Object"].to_list()
```

Comment: No, i didn't mean that. I have STARS, RA and DEC arrays as 

STARS=['WASP-80', 'SAO-206462', '2MJ0944', 'FOMALHAUT-C'...'V-AP-COL']

but the code inside for loop must seek all of these names, however it only seeks for the first term: 'WASP-80'

Comment: If you run my code and type print(STARS), you'll see that the array has the names from .tsv file. But the for loop cannot pick these names